# Why does the camera use a flash even though I have turned flash off?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, camera

I have the flash turned off on my phone:

[image: camera settings]

But when I take pictures, it flashes. Even outdoors in broad daylight. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's probably the focus assist feature, which uses the flash *before* actually taking the picture, to focus the scene.

To disable this in the default Camera app:

1. Expand the app bar by tapping on the three dots
2. Select "photo settings..."
3. Set "Focus Assist Light" to "Off"

In the Nokia Camera app:

1. Expand the app bar by tapping on the three dots
2. Select "settings"
3. Set "Focus assist light" to "always off". Alternatively, set it to "set by flash", so it will only be enabled when flash is enabled.

Comment: what would be the consequences? Less focused pictures?

Comment: It's possible that focusing will be slower, or the camera will fail to focus properly. This should only be a problem in low-light scenarios, so you'll have to experiment with the setting yourself. Personally I use Nokia Camera and set it to "set by flash".